# Update table using parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure that gets these parameters:

```
@TaskId        UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
@ColumnName    VARCHAR(255) = NULL,
@CheckBoxValue VARCHAR(255) = NULL
```

Then I have an `UPDATE` statement like this:

```
UPDATE [RedMarkItems]
SET @ColumnName = @CheckBoxValue
WHERE [TaskId] = @TaskId
```

If I run my stored procedure like:

```
exec usp_RedMarkItem_Insert 
         @TaskId = '82ab0c4b-9342-46fa-acbe-c00b87571bf9', 
         @ColumnName = Item7, 
         @CheckBoxValue = 1, 
         @CurrentUser = '6074caea-7a8e-4699-9451-16c2eaf394ef'
```

It does not affect table just says

> Commands completed successfully

But values still the same, but if I replace values in UPDATE statement like

```
UPDATE [RedMarkItems]
SET Item7 = 1
WHERE [TaskId] = '82ab0c4b-9342-46fa-acbe-c00b87571bf9'
```

It works! Why is it not working if I use parameters? Regards

Comment: You need to use `dynamic sql` for this.  You are just updating the local field, not the column in the database...

Comment: Your usp_RedMarkItem_Insert stored procedure does an update? Are you sure you are calling the right thing? That UPDATE should actually error for the reasons the anwers below stated.

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean actually, T-SQL is oddly happy with that syntax. In this case, it'll assign the value of `@CheckBoxValue` to `@ColumnName`: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=db36d9420e470dec76344fac8e8a7578)

Comment: @Larnu Any update statement on a table should require a column be referenced in the SET. Maybe Microsoft can fix that omission in syntax checking. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The mistake you're making here is you're under the impression that a variable/parameter can be used in place for an object's name. Simply put, it can't. An object's name must be a literal, so you can't do something like:

```
DECLARE @TableName sysname;
SET @TableName = N'MyTable';

SELECT *
FROM @TableName;
```

For things like this you need to use dynamic SQL, and (just as importantly) **secure** dynamic SQL.

Firstly, I would change `@ColumnName` to the datatype `sysname` (which is a synonym for `nvarchar(128)`) and `@Checkbox` to a `bit` (A Checkbox can have only 3 values: `True`/`1`, `False`/`0` and `NULL`, so an `nvarchar(255)` is a very poor data choice). Then your Stored Procedure will look something like:

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

SELECT @SQL = N'UPDATE RedMarkItems' + NCHAR(10) +
              N'SET ' + QUOTENAME(c.[name]) + N' = @Checkbox' + NCHAR(10) +
              N'WHERE TaskID = @ID;'
FROM sys.tables t
     JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
WHERE c.[name] = @ColumnName
  AND t.[name] = 'RedMarkItems';

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@Checkbox bit, @ID uniqueindentifier', @Checkbox = @CheckBoxValue, @ID = @TaskId;
```

The reason for the references to the `sys` tables is to ensure that the column does indeed exist. If it does not, then no SQL will be run. This is just an extra safety measure, alongside the use of `QUOTENAME`.

Comment: This. Anytime we've needed to do anything funky with columns or tables as a variable, we always check the database tables for an exact match to get a validated column or table name. FYI, wrapping the table and columns with brackets ([]) is a good idea in case the table or column is a reserved word or contains spaces, etc. We have the column "key" on one of our tables :(

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean I assume by *"wrapping the table and columns with brackets ([]) "* you don't mean things like `'...FROM [' + @TableName + N']...;` which is also wide open to injection.

Comment: Of course not, we would generate the SQL as you have but wrap the columns and table names with brackets.

Answer (score 2):

What you did was set @ColumnName equal to the value in @CheckBoxValue 0 or more times (based on how many rows exist in the table).  Likely not what you intended...

Instead, you will either want to use dynamic SQL (`set @sql = 'UPDATE … ' + QUOTENAME(@ColumnName) + 'rest of sql'`) or otherwise build a case statement to handle each column based on the value you are trying to update dynamically.  SQL needs to bind the statement at compile time, so you need to have that available at compile time for the query processor to make sure that the column is real, has the right types to do type derivation, etc.  Using parameters as you did would prevent all of that logic from working (assuming the semantics were as you intended in your posted question).

Please be careful as SQL injection attacks are possible on non-validated parameters.  You would want to make sure that the column name is a valid column name and not something that allows arbitrary SQL code execution under the context of the running transaction.

Comment: `UPDATE … ' + @ColumnName +` isn't a good idea, considering that the value of `@ColumnName` has been unsanitised. It'll leave the OP's SP wide open to injection. I know you've stated to "to be careful" about injection, but you would be far better showing the OP how to avoid it, rather than simply having an example of unsanitised string concatenation.

Comment: fair enough - guidance on how to validate inputs is listed on this page and can be used to validate the parameter.  Without knowing the driver/language, it is hard to give a useful example to the OP, but this works for ado.net: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/sql-injection?view=sql-server-2017